# Inner div with 100% height of parent div

Tags: html, css

Hi I search for reason why my inner divs don´t have 100% height. i check a lot o threads here and on internet, but nothing work. I need website which have content with same width and height as browser content = for that I need all divs with height of browser height. I search for CSS only solution (= no CCS3, no Javascript/Jquery, etc..).

```
<div class="obsah">
    <div class="obsah_in_1_3">
    obsah1
    </div>
    <div class="obsah_in_2_3">
    obsah2
    </div>
    <div class="obsah_in_3_3">
    obsah3
    </div>
</div>

html, body{
  height: 100%;
}
.menu{
  position: relative;
  float: left;
    width: 260px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height:auto !important;
  background-color: green;
}
.obsah_in_1_3 {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height:auto !important;
}
.obsah_in_2_3 {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  background-color: #00FF00;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height:auto !important;
}
.obsah_in_3_3 {
  float: left;
  width: 34%;
  background-color: #0000FF;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height:auto !important;
}
.obsah{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height:auto !important;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Here is [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b25hZ/1/)

I try used absolute position with `bottom: 0px;` to inner divs (obsah_in_1_3, obsah_in_2_3, obsah_in_3_3) and this work, but I need have floating divs, because after solved this problem I need change their width with Jquery nd they need float together.
=> simply I don´t know why inner divs (obsah_in_1_3, obsah_in_2_3, obsah_in_3_3) not work and div "menu" work and these divs are same.

Comment: But CSS3 doesn't supported in older browsers..

Comment: But CSS3 not work in older browser => I need simply CSS. We support IE7 and sometimes IE6 => CSS3 things is not idel way for me.

Comment: The problem is due to using `float: left` .. while set float to the inner div its not inherited the parent's size...

Comment: That it doesn't support older browsers is another story(and true), but in fact CSS3 is also CSS.

Comment: But when I kick off "float:left" then nothing change. If I add, after that, something like "display: block" or "display: inline-block" then still nothing change...

Comment: Why do you have `height: 100%;` and then two lines below it `height: auto !important;` ?

Comment: arandompenguin: I found it in some thread here, I mean this is for old browser, new browser etc.. I mean this is useless, but if these lines helped someone with similiar problem then I try it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not any *large reason* you are use *two* times *height* property with *different value* that's why *not work*,

#### Check this <kbd>**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q953L/1/)**</kbd>

`position: relative;` another `display: block;` and third `height: 100%;` this three properties are great roll to archive 100% height.

#### CSS

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
.hlavicka{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 260px;
    height:100%;
    background-color: grey;
}
.obsah_in_1_3 {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    height: 100%;
}
.obsah_in_2_3 {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    background-color: #00FF00;
    height: 100%;
}
.obsah_in_3_3 {
    float: left;
    width: 34%;
    background-color: #0000FF;
    height: 100%;
}
.obsah{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Hope now this help you!

Comment: Hmm It so badly I can accept only one answer..And I accept 1st answer sorry. But I upvote this.

Comment: you have to wait for couple of minutes for taking answer. and i m give answer with clear indication. no problem accept answer not important you got solution its important. always welcome :) have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Height 100% means you can add the content in div & the height changes according to div. You can set height in pixels or you can get the Window resolution and set the height of the div according.

Comment: When I get Window height and add it to div then I need some JS. How can I get Height of window with pure HTML/CSS ?

Comment: @SevereTorture, check out CSS media queries. Here's a good resource: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: I know media queries = they check browser size i don´t know why can they add this size to some CSS. => We have a lot of different monitors, a lot of different browser with a lot of different height of browser window (some ugly panels etc..) => When someone have 800pxheight of browser then I add with media queries 800px to my divs ok, but when someone have 790px? Then I wrote next media queries... When someone have 780px then 3rd queries etc.. ? If I understand well this is not dynamic path. I understand this right?

Answer (score 1):

Take out height:auto !important from your parent and child divs.  Height 100% should do what you need.

Comment: Doesn't change anything that I can see.